# what is the advantage of DisplayName attribute than Display attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, displayattribute

The result of `[DisplayName("foo")]` and `[Display(Name="foo")]` for `@Html.LabelFor(x => x.MyProperty)` is same. both generate `<label for="MyProperty">foo</label>`. what is the advantage of DisplayName?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Display` attribute should be preferred over `DisplayName` attribute. The former one comes form `DataAnnotations` namespace and exposes more properties than the later one, ie. ShortName, Prompt, GroupName, Order, Description, which are used by `DataAnnotationsMetadataProvider`.

Most importantly, `DisplayName` accepts only literals, while `Display` accepts resource type and key, which can be used to provide translations using separate resource files (resx).

Answer (score 3):

Can't really say that there is some advantage of using one over the other. `DisplayName` exists in older versions of the framework while `Display` can be used only in ASP.NET MVC 3 as it was introduced in .NET 4.0.